# Can I receive a projection of an entity from the server?

Tags: c#, web-services, entity-framework

I have an entity data model and a domain service (it may be a RIA service - I don't know) like this:

```
[EnableClientAccess]
public class MyService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<NORTHWNDEntities>
{
    public IQueryable<Categories> GetCategories()  
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Categories;
    }  
}
```

From what I understand this class is on the server and the method `GetCategoriesQuery()` can be called from the client:

```
MyContext context = new MyContext();
IQueryable<Categories> p = context.GetCategoriesQuery();
```

I would like to receive from the server a projection of the `Categories` entity or maybe a join of some entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, return an anonymous type from your method, from a projection?  Then, no, because you can't return any anonymous type from a method.  You'll have to define a class to project into to return it.  Or you could return a Tuple<>.